# blank paper report6i

Tags: runtime-error, oraclereports

I create a simple report with `report 6i` to perform the following query:

`SELECT ALL EMP.EMPNO, EMP.ENAME, 
EMP.JOB, EMP.MGR, EMP.HIREDATE, EMP.SAL, EMP.COMM, EMP.DEPTNO
FROM EMP`

the report compile with no error 
and I call it in form 6i using  button and 
`when-button-pressed` trigger and I call the report as following

`Run_Product(REPORTS,'d:\emp', SYNCHRONOUS, RUNTIME,filesystem,'', NULL);`

and also gives no error butt when I run the form and press the button 
it gives my blank report I want to know what am I missing to making it work 
thank u

*I am using windows 7-64bit  and database 10g and I install batch 18

Comment: I found the the `error` it seem I replace the folder where the report was

thank u stackers